# Use a bot as a user on Telegram

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

I'm using https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api and I'm able to send message to user and to my channels. I'd like to improve my bot, I want to manage the private messages that my bot receives.

At the moment when the BOT receive a message, I can save on database from my node application, but if I want to manage all messages, I need to build a backoffice.

Is it possible to read the messages from Telegram and impersonate the BOT and start a normal conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Using Telegram bot, Telegram does not provide any function to retrieve old messages. BOT API does not have such feature.

What you need is to use TDlib - The Telegram client API. It supports both bot and normal Telegram account. And it has many features not available in BOT API.

https://github.com/tdlib/td

Answer (score -1):

There is an example of creating a Userbot on this github page: [UserBot](https://github.com/spelsinx/tg-userbot-js)

There is also a library for managing a telegram account, which is used to create cross-platform telegram clients: [TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: it will not change, because I am the creator of the repository and, I confirm that I will not delete the repository, you will not be able to find help on creating a Userbot on nodejs/js only if on pure queries, but again, this cannot be found.